# Google Drive API - Get file and zip with JSZip is returning corrupt file

Tags: javascript, api, zip, drive, jszip

I'm using [Google Drive's API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) to get the BLOB of a file and attempting to give that BLOB data to [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_name.html) to zip, but I'm having issues.

The specific snippet looks like this:

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+file_id+"?alt=media",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "responseType": "blob",
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+bearer_token
     }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response, status, xhr) {
    console.log(response);
    zip.file(filename, response);

    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}, function updateCallback(metadata) {
        var msg = "progression : " + metadata.percent.toFixed(2) + " %";
        if(metadata.currentFile) {
            msg += ", current file = " + metadata.currentFile;
        }
        showMessage(msg);
        updatePercent(metadata.percent|0);
     })
     .then(function callback(blob) {
         saveAs(blob, "example.zip");
         showMessage("done !");
     }, function (e) {
         showError(e);
     });
 });
```

I used Postman to do the API testing which was returning expected results. I've tried zipping several image/pdf/zip files all of which have come back corrupted. The only thing that has worked so far has been a PHP file. Google Drive API is returning the BLOB data properly and everything looks right in JSZip generated zip file (file name, file size, etc.) but upon opening the file from the zip I get errors that indicate the file is corrupt.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help, in advance!

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay! Thank you so much for your help. It worked! Your changes helped to create the BLOB URL which I was able to implement into JSZip by replacing my original zip.file function with zip.file(filename, urlToPromise(URL.createObjectURL(blob)), {binary:true}); and now the zip file is returning an uncorrupted file.

Comment: Thank you for replying and your additional information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve a zip file from Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using Javascript.
- You have already been able to get and put the file using Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- I think that the reason of your issue is that the zip file is retrieved as the string data.

  - For this situation, I used `fetch`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+file_id+"?alt=media",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "responseType": "blob",
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+bearer_token
     }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response, status, xhr) {
```

To:

```
const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file_id + "?alt=media";
fetch(url, {
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "binary",
  responseType: "blob",
  headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + bearer_token},
  // crossDomain: true, // This might not be required.
})
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(response => {
```

- In above modified script, `response` is a blob.
- Please set `file_id` and `bearer_token`

#### For testing:

As a test sample script, how about the following script? When you run this script, the downloaded zip file is saved to the local PC as the filename of `sample.zip`. I thought that the script might be able to be tested using this script.

```
const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file_id + "?alt=media";
fetch(url, {
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "binary",
  responseType: "blob",
  headers: {Authorization: "Bearer "+bearer_token},
})
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.target = "_blank";
  a.download = "sample.zip";
  a.click();
});
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

#### References:

- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: the reason why he fail was that he used responseType in the header, and fetch don't support `dataType` or `responseType` so that options should be gone.